# Linear independence of x \sin(x) and x\abs{\sin(x)} on (-2\pi, 2pi)?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on a question that asks me first to determine whether $ \{ x \sin(x),\; x\,|\sin(x)|\}$ constitute a linearly independent set on $I = (-2\pi, 2\pi)$ and then to show that the Wronskian of these functions exists.

However, it seems to me that they are not linearly independent on $I$ because of (at least) the points $x = 0, \pm\pi$, for which the determinant of the matrix of coefficients would be zero. e.g., using the points $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = \pi/2$ we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cdot 0 &  0 \\ \frac{\pi}{2} & \frac{\pi}{2}\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},$$

where the determinant is clearly zero.

Similarly, if we wanted to prove linear independence via the Wronskian, one of the conditions is that the functions be differentiable on $I$; however, I thought that $\frac{d}{dx}x\,|\sin(x)| = |\sin(x)| + \frac{\sin(x)}{|\sin(x)|}\cos(x)$, which is not defined at $x = 0, \pm \pi$.

What am I missing? Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: There are (sub-)intervals over which they are the same functions and (sub-)intervals over which they are opposite functions, so how can they be linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes, there is also that. While the first question (viz. re: linear independence) could certainly be answered "no", the 2nd part of the question asks to show that the Wronskian exists and then to calculate it, which doesn't make sense to me unless there is some rule that allows one to exclude the individual points?

Comment: Well, $\left|\sin x\right|$ is not differentiable at some points, but the Wronskian is still well-defined on $E=\mathbb{R}\setminus\pi\mathbb{Z}$. So, just compute the Wronskian over $E$.

Comment: So that would just mean there'd be something funky going on at the zeros and a different analysis would be necessary to solve the DE at these points? In practice, is this an issue? Thank you kindly for your guidance.

Comment: The derivative of $x|\sin x|$ is $0$ at $x=0$. You can apply the definition directly to $f(x)=x|\sin x|$. All you have to show is that $|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}-0|\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you - always back to basics. Should've thought of using the limit definition.

Comment: Another reason for which $\sin x$ and $\left|\sin x\right|$ cannot be linearly dependent is that they do not have the same regularity: the first function is a $C^1$ function over the given interval, the latter is not. A similar argument applies to $x\sin x$ and $x\left|\sin x\right|$.